# Clear an already set "fill" property in CSS to get defaults back for an SVG

Tags: css, svg, fill

I'm using a platform that within it's own CSS it sets the `fill` property as so:

```
.tatsu-svg-icon-custom svg * {
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

This ends up with an SVG I am adding being *black* in this instance - which is not helpful. This particular SVG is a multi-colored SVG and handles all the `fill` properties itself within the code of the SVG.

Obviously if I change this property to aother color, it colors the whole SVG that color - so that is not helpful either.

So my question is, how do I get the defaults back so it doesn't apply *any* color to it? Setting it to `initial` makes the SVG transparent.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understood your question correctly, but if you can edit the CSS, why can you not delete the fill property from it, so that it doesn't affect the svg? Also, if you can edit the SVG, you might be able to give the elements, which would be affected by the fill a specific class and use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to make that class not be affected by that specific CSS part.

Comment: Could you edit (or reexport) the svg so that each element within the SVG had its fill set by inline css, like style="fill: yellow" ?

Comment: @Geshode I could, but because it's a third-party platform it will just come back when the platform is updated for example. As for now, I have just reverted to putting it in as an image, rather than using the `svg` tag.

Comment: @aptriangle I suppose I could, but seems a bit overkill. For now I have reverted to using an `img` tag instead. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword that would help in this situation is [`revert-layer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert-layer). Unfortunately, it is currently only implemented in Firefox (>= 97).

(This example will seem to work even for other browsers. But that is because for them, it is an invalid keyword.)

```css
.tatsu-svg-icon-custom svg * {
    fill: revert-layer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tatsu-svg-icon-custom">
  <svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <circle r="5" cx="5" cy="5" fill="yellow" />
    <circle r="5" cx="5" cy="15" fill="blue" />
    <circle r="5" cx="15" cy="5" fill="red" />
    <circle r="5" cx="15" cy="15" fill="green" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Wouldn't `revert` also work here? Just tried it and it seems to :)

Comment: It didn't for me on Firefox 108

Comment: You're right. I mistakenly thought it worked, as it made the color transparent, and for the particular SVG that worked well, as it only affected part of it - but tried it on another, and not so good - made the whole thing transparent.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  Apparently, some chromium based browsers also support `revert-layer`  (like Opera). In Dev tools it's displayed as a valid property value (even though not implemented as autocomplete option). Unfortunately, iOS safari struggles with this. You might add the initial `fill: currentColor`  rule to your snippet (currently there is nothing to override).