# Unset fill black

Tags: css, google-visualization

The Google Visualization Chart is filled with a color if the `fill` css property is set, e.g.

```css
* {
  fill: black;
}
```

Is there a way to unset the CSS `fill` property so that it uses the original colors? The goal is not to modify the Chart component is any way, the `fill` is unrelated to the chart (can be used to change other SVGs) but it affects the chart.

This does not work:

```css
#chart_div * {
  fill: unset;
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g37fjyLx/1/

I realize that setting the `fill` for all elements `*` is probably not a good idea, but I'd still like to know if there is a way to reset it.

Comment: Actually, I would expect the Google Chart component to override the `fill`. Can this be considered a bug? Or is it by design, you should be able to override SVG style with CSS?

Comment: Applying a super general style rule like `*{fill:black}`  is always questionable since you will most likely need more overriding rules. So why do you need this first override at all? As a last resort you could use `fill:revert-layer`` as described her: [Clear an already set "fill" property in CSS to get defaults back for an SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092966/clear-an-already-set-fill-property-in-css-to-get-defaults-back-for-an-svg/75095961#75095961). But I really doubt, you can't get the desired result wit a nice and clean css structure.

Comment: Yeah, we removed the `* { fill: black }` because it might have caused other issues. I was still curious to know if it was possible. It seems that `revert-layer` did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use **backgroundColor.fill**.  Please refer this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#configuration-options

```
var options = {
  height: 275,
  backgroundColor: { fill: "#333" } 
};
```

Comment: Sure, but that was not the question. The intent was not to change background color, it want to unset `fill`. I will clarify the question.

Comment: I think you need to select specific child elements of SVG and unset the fill.

Comment: You mean for each child in the SVG?

Comment: I tried `#chart_div path {  fill: unset; }`, but that does not work either.

Comment: `#chart_div path{
  fill: none;
}

#chart_div rect{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #333;
}`

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't restore the original (as when `fill` is not set at all).

Comment: I don't think it is possible to restore it properly. It doesn't matter, there are other (better) ways to solve the issue I had, I was just curious if it was possible.

Comment: See comment above, it was possible using `fill: revert-layer`.

Answer (score -1):

use this for your color:

```
  var options = {
    height: 275,
    gantt: {
        criticalPathEnabled: false, // Critical path arrows will be the same as other arrows.
        arrow: {
          angle: 100,
          width: 5,
          color: 'blue',
          radius: 0
        }
      }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, I just clarified the question. The goal is not to modify the chart, but to undo the effect `fill` has on the chart.